# dfrac no larger than frac

Tags: packages, fractions

I'm making a compound fraction for a review worksheet. I currently have this:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}

\item
Simplify
\[
\dfrac{\frac{3}{5} + \frac{5}{5x}}{1 - \frac{1}{10x}}
\]
```

The problem is that the fractions 3/5 are extremely tiny. If I replace \dfrac with \frac, I see that they are exactly the same. I want the main fraction to be large, and the smaller fractions to be normal. Am I missing a package? Is there a better way to get what I need?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In display math environment in such simple case both should have the same size.  Try difference in `\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}` and  `\frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{2}}`.

Comment: The outer `\dfrac` is not doing anything as it is already in display mode, you could use `\dfrac` for the inner ones, or you could put `\Large` before the `\[`

Answer (score 10):

Make your choice! `nccmath` defines a `\mfrac` command (`medium-sized` fractions, about 80 % of displaystyle):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
          Simplify
          \[
            \frac{\frac{3}{5} + \frac{5}{5x}}{1 - \frac{1}{10x}} = \frac{\mfrac{3}{5} + \mfrac{5}{5x}}{1 - \mfrac{1}{10x}} = \frac{\dfrac{3}{5} + \dfrac{5}{5x}}{1 - \dfrac{1}{10x}}
          \]
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]